# MGTwitterEngine Iphone oAuth

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, mgtwitterengine

I hve try the MGTwitterEngine for oAuth from source https://github.com/kimptoc/MGTwitterEngine-1.0.8-OAuth

I am using this code for the MGTwitterEngine oAuth... but not working for me...

it give the same error I was getting in using xAuth without enabling xAuth [Twitter integrated in Iphone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468353/twitter-integrated-in-iphone-app/4468466#4468466)

Error Log is:

```
Twitter request failed! (3AFB8476-929F-4467-A4FE-DE43358CB62A) Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.) ((null))
```

and one more thing I have not found anything in the for setting the application key and secret?

may be error due to this.. please help me.

**Edited**
*Code on twitter button tab*

```
-(IBAction)twitterBtnAct:(id)sender{
    // Put your Twitter username and password here:
    NSString *username = @"username";
    NSString *password = @"password";

    // Make sure you entered your login details before running this code... ;)
    if ([username isEqualToString:@""] || [password isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"You forgot to specify your username/password in AppController.m!");
    }

    // Create a TwitterEngine and set our login details.
    twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [twitterEngine setUsername:username password:password];

    // Get updates from people the authenticated user follows.
    [twitterEngine getFollowedTimelineFor:username since:nil startingAtPage:0];
}
```

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone for oAuth

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401 errors are about authentication problems. In the project, the application does:

```
 twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
 [twitterEngine setUsername:username password:password]
```

Have you set this in your app?

Comment: I have done these.. I have add the code in question which I am using